# Printing the first 6 files in a current directory using the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I am trying to work out how to use the terminal. Does anyone know how I can print the first 7 file names of a current directory? I am using:

```
ls
```

to print all of the files. How can I print the first 7? I hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe it into head like this

```
ls | head -7
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).